# A small problem with tex rendering after an edit

Tags: bug, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing appears to affect maths-display](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/editing-appears-to-affect-maths-display)

Sometimes I get some tex rendering (small) problem after I edit my questions.

I am adding a screenshot from my latest question where I say the problem again.

This post is to notify the person how might want to know and fix any problems (if there are any)

I am running FF 15.0.1 on Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Another example is where the word char is at the first line

Comment: This is probably the same bug [reported here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6166/242)

Comment: This goes away when I refresh, but it is still worth fixing.

Comment: @robjohn - refreshing works for me to. I just wanted to report te bug

Comment: I agree. I added that it was still worth fixing because I didn't want the fact that refreshing "works around" the bug to keep anyone from fixing it. It is also great that you reported it.